# Asp.net Core Docker container outbound HTTPS calls failing

Tags: curl, docker, asp.net-core

I am using the following Dockerfile to create a container for my ASP.NET Core application:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.2
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY PublishOutput .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityServer4.Management.dll"]
```

It seems that if my container has to make any outbound calls via HTTPS, an exception is thrown, referencing curl:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.CurlException: SSL connect error
```

This seems to happen even when the remote side has a **valid certificate**. I have been able to bypass this by attaching the following HttpHandlerto an HttpClient, which seems to bypass the issues:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
```

What am I missing here, and why am I having to do this as a workaround?

Upon trying to research this, I came across some discussions that a "client certificate" is needed to establish this connection, with no concrete examples.

Also, I am technically using Rancher for our Docker management system, which has a set of infrastructure that these containers run on. Not sure if that makes a difference at all, but figured I would mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that I was running this on the internal company network, and that my company security department issued certs for internal applications, I had to add the CA Chain Cert to my container in order by it to recognize my company as a valid authority.  I added these to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -o /usr/share/ca-certificates/my_ca_chain.crt https://somelocation/my_ca_chain.crt
RUN echo "my_ca_chain.crt" >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf && update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!

If I could give a thousand likes for this, I would!

Having very little SSL experience at the start, I literally spent months trying to figure out why I couldnt get SSL connections working in our Rancher system with multiple APIs that we are writing, then came across this which put the missing peice into place...

Eternally grateful for your work and comment!